# How to get rounded corners, borders in MATE menu?

Tags: menu, mate

I'm running Ubuntu MATE, I removed the default menu and added the "MATE Menu" to my panel. I'm using all default themes/settings. The menu is very boxy and doesn't seem to really have a noticeable border (so if something beneath the menu is the same color as the menu it looks like it all blends in together). Suggestions?